# Nested block programming

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

According to this block programming tutorial:

http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/

The following nested block:

```
void (^(^myblockptr)(void (^)()))();
```

Is a pointer to a block returning a block taking a block

It says that it is equivalent to:

```
typedef void (^Block)();
Block (^myblockptr)(Block);
```

I guess that `(void (^)())` corresponds to the parameters, i.e, `(Block)`. However, I am unable to see which part of the nested expression corresponds to the returned block.

Are you able to identify the returned block in the nested expression?

Comment: [declare myblockptr as block (block returning void) returning block returning void](http://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28%5E%28%5Emyblockptr%29%28void+%28%5E%29%28%29%29%29%28%29%3B)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Joshua’s said, when analysing C declarations it’s a good idea to start from the inside out.

```
void (^(^myblockptr)(void (^)()))();
```

Since `myblockptr` is the variable, let’s split the declaration in two parts, to the left of the variable and to the right of the variable:

```
void (^(^myblockptr)    (void (^)()))();
```

We know that `(^myblockptr)` is a block because of `^`, so to its left we should find its return type, and to its right we should find its parameter types.

Let’s analyse the parameters that `myblockptr` takes, moving to the right. They should be grouped by parentheses right after the `(^myblockptr)`:

```
void (^(^myblockptr)    (void (^)())    )();
```

It’s a single parameter, which is a block because of `^`:

```
void (^)()
```

and now it’s easy to see that the parameter is a block that returns `void` and takes no parameters.

Moving farther to the right, there’s a closing parenthesis so we need to analyse the leftmost part:

```
void (^    (^myblockptr)…
```

where we see that `myblockptr` returns a block that returns `void`. Since it returns a block, we should find the parameter types accepted by the returned block after the closing parenthesis that matches the leftmost opening paranthesis:

```
void (^    (^myblockptr)(void (^)())    )();
```

since it’s `()`, we see that the returned block doesn’t have any parameters.

[image]

In summary: `myblockptr` is a block that (to the right) accepts a parameter that is a *block that takes no parameters and returns `void`* and (to the left) returns a *block that takes no parameters and returns `void`*. Since the return type of `myblockptr` and the (single) parameter type are the same:

```
typedef void (^Block)();
```

leading to:

```
Block (^myblockptr)(Block);
```

You may want to read [Steve’s Reading C type declarations](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) and, as mentioned by Jeremy, [Fish’s cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You should read the block definition from the inside out.

Lets break it down.

`void (^(^myblockptr)(void (^)()))();`

`void (^)()` declares a block which is a parameter

`RETURNTYPE (^myblockptr)(PARAMS)` declares a block named `myblockptr` with params

and the external void (^(....)()) refers to the return type from the block.

Putting it all together gets you the original declaration.